# error: App 'polls' could not be found. Is it in INSTALLED_APPS? *But polls is in INSTALLED_APPS in settings.py. I

Tags: python, django

I am trying to create the 'polls' part of my Django project/website and the tutorial (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/intro/tutorial01/) says that before we 'activate' the models we have to include 'polls' in the INSTALLED_APPS library in settings.py. I did that, then I do--> $ python manage.py make migrations polls. This gives me the error--> App 'polls' could not be found. is it in INSTALLED_APPS?. What do I do from here?! I synced my database after I added polls, still doesn't work.

```
172-16-22-166:mysite manuelgomez$ cd
172-16-22-166:~ manuelgomez$ cd mysite
172-16-22-166:mysite manuelgomez$ ls
chocolate   llama       nuts        story
db.sqlite3  manage.py   polls       urls.py
fts     mysite      settings.py
172-16-22-166:mysite manuelgomez$ python manage.py migrate 
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, contenttypes, auth, sessions
Running migrations:
  No migrations to apply.
172-16-22-166:mysite manuelgomez$ python manage.py syncdb 
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, contenttypes, auth, sessions
Running migrations:
  No migrations to apply.
172-16-22-166:mysite manuelgomez$ python manage.py makemigrations polls
App 'polls' could not be found. Is it in INSTALLED_APPS?
172-16-22-166:mysite manuelgomez$
```

Comment: Did you create the app? python manage.py startapp polls ?

Comment: Please add your `settings` and directory structure of `polls`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In settings.py you will find INSTALLED_APPS and you must add the polls as shown below.

```
    INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'polls'
]
```

Answer (score 3):

add setting like this
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ...
    'you_app_name',
)

Answer (score 3):

a simple : `python manage.py makemigrations` do the trick for me and will detect your models and make migrations

Comment: This indeed works but can you explain to me why is this so ? I'm new to django and I don't quite get what was the problem. Is it for example something that changed from django 1.x to 2.0?

Answer (score 1):

Remove the app from comand. Example: `python manage.py makemigrations`

Answer (score 1):

Did you check database?
You should find "your app" at 'app' column in "Django_migrations" table.
if not, you should type "python manage.py migrate" command, "DJANGO_MIGRATIONS" table is created.
(In case of using window and cmd, you should restart cmd.)
Good luck.