# Django - makemigrations - No changes detected/Apps could not be found

Tags: python, django

I was trying to create migrations within an existing app using the `makemigrations` command but it outputs "No changes detected".

The code I used for that is

```
python3 manage.py makemigrations
```

I tried:

```
python3 manage.py makemigrations polls
```

and it shows

> "App 'polls' could not be found. Is it in INSTALLED_APPS?"

Here is my `INSTALLED_APPS` of the 'settings.py' file

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'polls.apps.PollsConfig',
]
```

I know some people simply put 'polls', it doesn't work either

Here is my folder structure:

[image]

Here is my 'apps.py':

```
from django.apps import AppConfig
class PollsConfig(AppConfig):
name = 'polls'
```

Here is my urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
urlpatterns = [
path('', views.index, name='index'),
path('new', views.new),
]
```

I am using django2.1 and python3.8.

Comment: share yout urls.py file.

Comment: If this your actual code from apps.py including offsets and quotes?

Comment: I shared my urls.py

Comment: Does this answer your question? [error: App 'polls' could not be found. Is it in INSTALLED\_APPS? \*But polls is in INSTALLED\_APPS in settings.py. I](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31838377/error-app-polls-could-not-be-found-is-it-in-installed-apps-but-polls-is-in)

Comment: I have tried to add 'polls' in the INSTALLED_APPS as some people suggested, but it's the same result

Comment: Aren't there any errors or warning in concole when you're starting this project?